# How can I access SAP HANA calculation view in SQL console

Tags: c#, .net, hana

I am trying to access HANA calculation view using SQL console. But I can't find any information about it. Purpose to access this view or model from .NET connector. If anyone knows anything regarding that, that would be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty straight forward.
Every information view that got activated has a corresponding runtime object in schema _SYS_BIC.
So, if your calc view is e.g. called com.mycorp.myapp.USEREXPENSES (com.mycorp.myapp would be the package hierarchy) then you could query your calculation view with

```
SELECT * 
FROM "_SYS_BIC"."com.mycorp.myapp.USEREXPENSES"
```

Depending on the aggregation you do in the calc. view you may want to add additional GROUP BY conditions.

As of SPS10 SAP HANA Studio also allows to automatically insert the correct runtime object name into the SQL editor when you drag'n'drop the design time object over into the text area.
I've described this feature in [The 7th Niceness of new toys'n'tools](https://scn.sap.com/community/hana-in-memory/blog/2015/07/06/the-niceness-of-new-toysntools).

Comment: hi how can i get view column metadata using sql..i am not able ti find correct keyword